# How to create a variable and set it to a multi-line JSX structure in react-native

Tags: react-native

I feel super dumb when asking this, but I really couldn't find a way to do it. I know it's possible with return (...); And I also know I can set it to a singleline JSX component, but what if I need a multi-line?

Let's say I have the following JSX structure:

```
<View>
   <FontAwesome5 solid name={'someicon'}/>
   <Text>This is some text</Text>
</View>
```

As I said, I could do:

```
return (
<View>
   <FontAwesome5 solid name={'someicon'}/>
   <Text>This is some text</Text>
</View>
);
```

But in this function, I need to add some logic and I need to create a variable to avoid repeating code or function calls.

Attempted doing:

```
let result = ( ... );
let result = [ ... ];
let result = { ... };
let result = () => { ... };
let result = () => ( ... );
```

None worked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.itemsJSX = (
    <View>
       <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

  render() {
      return (
        this.itemsJSX
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: But if i do that, it throws red screen with: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Comment: OMG i feel sooo dumb. It was because i had a semi-colon at the end of the <Text> component that i couldn't see because of the width of my screen.